# why I am getting error when to export a model in tensorflow? The error is showing on picture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

can anyone say why I am getting error on the following line?

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(path+'models/'+model_name+'_graph.pbtxt',None,False,path+'models/har_model.chkp-1',output_node_name,path+'save/restore_all',path+'save/Const:0',path+'models/frozen_'+model_name+'.pb',True,"")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DeIb.png)

My task is to save a LSTM model so that I can use it in Android smartphone. I have done the following task till now.

```
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
import tensorflow as tf

input_node_name = ['lstm_1_input']
output_node_name = 'output/Softmax'
model_name = 'har_model'

graph_def_txt_path = path+'models/' + model_name + '_graph.pbtxt'
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
tf.io.write_graph(sess.graph_def, path+'models', model_name+'_graph.pbtxt')

checkpoint_path = path+'models/' + model_name + '.chkp'  # Adjust the path for Colab
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint()
checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_path)

frozen_graph_path = path+'models/frozen_' + model_name + '.pb'
tf.io.write_graph(sess.graph_def, path+'models', graph_def_txt_path)
```

Then the error line coming

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(path+'models/'+model_name+'_graph.pbtxt',None,False,path+'models/har_model.chkp-1',output_node_name,path+'save/restore_all',path+'save/Const:0',path+'models/frozen_'+model_name+'.pb',True,"")
```

Comment: Please don't use an image to show text. Copy the text directly to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can save a model as a h5 file and reload it with much less code.

Let's say you have a simple LSTM model called har_model.

```
har_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True), tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
```

To save your model, use:

```
har_model.save("har_model_or_whatever_you_want_to_name_it.h5")
```

To upload and use your model, use:

```
har_model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model("har_model_or_whatever_you_want_to_name_it.h5")
har_model2.summary()
har_model2.predict(somedata)
```

`har_model2` should contain the same parameters and retain experience from training.